# API Gateway Returns Forbidden when string with "https://" is Posted

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an API Gateway endpoint setup that uses a Lambda function to store a URL in DynamoDB. When I POST a message with this in the body

```
"videoURL": "www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgpvCVkrV6M"
```

the endpoint works fine. It returns 200 and the DynamoDB record is updated.  However, when I POST this

```
"videoURL": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgpvCVkrV6M"
```

the endpoint returns a 403 Forbidden response and the DB record is not updated.

When I test inside API Gateway, the "https://" string is accepted.

I also have an API Key, a Usage Plan, a Client Certificate, and CORS Enabled (for local testing). I don't think any of these are the cause of my problem.

Does anyone have a guess as to why the "https://" string is causing a problem?

Comment: What does “When I test inside API Gateway” mean, how exactly does that differ from the other request you are making? Which you also described with “I have an API Gateway endpoint setup”, so I am not sure what’s supposed to be what here now in the first place. Sounds though, as if your request might not even make it to the actual API, but gets rejected somewhere along the way before that point already.

Comment: In the API Gateway Console, under the API's Resources, for each method there is a box labeled "TEST".  Clicking on that label takes you to a "Method Test" screen where you can populate a message's "Request Body" and send that message to the API.

Comment: @CBroe, I agree it does sound like the request is getting rejected before making it to the API.  Maybe it's being rejected by the WAF.

Comment: @AmosLong, you can Enable CloudWatch Logs for api gateway.

https://aws.amazon.com/pt/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudwatch-logs/#:~:text=Enable%20logging%20for%20your%20API%20and%20stage&text=On%20the%20Stage%20Editor%20pane,execution%20logs%20for%20all%20requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in my Web Application Firewall (WAF). When I created my firewall, I added the AWS-AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet collection. According to the [documentation of this rule set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/aws-managed-rule-groups-list.html), one of the rules is:

```
GenericRFI_BODY - Inspects the values of the request body and blocks requests attempting to exploit RFI (Remote File Inclusion) in web applications. Examples include patterns like ://.
```

Disabling this rule solved my problem. I can now successfully send in and store "https://" in my database.

However, this rule represents a best practice (or at least a good practice), and should not be disabled without considering the risk. By disabling this rule, I make my endpoint vulnerable Remote File Inclusion attacks. Since I have access to the endpoint and Lambda function definition, I could split my URL input in to two fields ("https" and "www.youtube...") and keep the rule enabled. For anyone else encountering this issue, you'll have to weigh the ease vs. risk of each approach.